# When Spring Boot starts up, it throws the "method names must be tokens" exception

Tags: java, spring

When Spring Boot starts up, it throws the `method names must be tokens` exception

```
2016-08-11 16:53:54.499  INFO 14212 --- [0.1-8888-exec-1] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:462) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:994) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]

2016-08-11 16:53:58.885  INFO 14212 --- [0.1-8888-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-08-11 16:53:58.888  INFO 14212 --- [0.1-8888-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-08-11 16:53:58.922  INFO 14212 --- [0.1-8888-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 30 ms
11111111-chinadfadf-xxxxxxxx@121.com
```

Anyone knows why it throws this exception?

Comment: Without the code and config it will be extremely hard to say

Comment: please add your code ;)

Comment: The error seems to be you're http method has no valid characters

Comment: I got the same exception when I locally tested. The problem was a url schema in my request. I used "https", but should "http". Probably it helps.

Comment: Change of the protocol mentioned in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49421859/1851289 had helped.

Answer (score 138):

This exception can occur when you try to execute https request from client on endpoint which isn't https enabled. Client will encrypt request data when server is expecting raw data.

Change https:// to http:// in your client url.

Comment: Any idea how to (redirect https to http || disable https || catch the error to at least show a meaningful error message)?

Comment: I've just stumbled across this issue. It is indeed an issue in tomcat that reflects on an unsupported SSL request, trying to be processed as-is, and of course failing (everything is read as garbled text, unparseable). I only think Tomcat should be able to detect and handle a little more gracefully? I'll open an issue later :D

Answer (score 8):

Another Case: SpringBoot and Tomcat use port 8080 or 8888 by default. I had a Jupyter Notebook running at the same time which has a token in it's url path and some random characters. Anyway: The Notebook was still trying to make requests when the jupyter notebook server was down.

If you encounter this error: Check if you have another Application running that is either spawning a webserver or talking to a webserver on such ports.

Comment: When downvoting an answer it would be helpful to explain why you did so. It would help me and others to understand the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The same problem.

```
cmd -> netstat -ano then find the port your have used(e.g 8888)
```

I find a process try send package not Http request to my 8888 port, so the tomcat throw the `method names must be tokens` Exception.

you can:

- change server port;
- find the process and kill it;

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was when Tomcat created HTTPS request without SSL certificate installed on it. To fix it I changed schema in request to HTTP. Or you should create SSL certificate to use HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

you must have added https intead of http i also was getting same error with given below code

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/myobject")
    public MyObject getMyObject() {
        return new MyObject("John Doe", true, 42);
    }
}
```

This is what i got with https
[image]

Also Error in IDE with stack trace

```
2023-03-22T03:32:56.767+05:30  INFO 21684 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x000xf70x010x000x000xf30x030x030x950xa2*tU0x050x1a0xe20xf5]0x1c0x8f0x070x160x0b9q10xa9d0x800xc50xdau0xfd0x8d*0xe00xec0xe80xd3C ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:272) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

and This is what i got with http only
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error using Spring Boot. The provided answers focused only on the error explanation and provided a way to use HTTP instead of HTTPS.

But in my case, we are already using TLS certicates. So the solution was to enable SSL by configuring the embedded Tomcat server through either the `application.yml` or `application.properties` file.

We only need to define these peroperties:

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:/path/to/keystore.p12
    key-store-password: password-to-access-keystore
    key-store-type: pkcs12
    key-alias: my-spring-boot-app
    key-password: password-for-the-private-key-if-you-have-any
    enabled: true
  port: 8443
```

The following documentation list all needed properties and their default values: [Spring Common Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.server)