# Body encoding in a request to Zuul

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, netflix-zuul

I encrypt the body on the client side. But when I receive it, the server thinks that I am using ssl and returns an error: "Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens", while in Zuul Filter I decrypt the body and pass it to other services. How do I disable this type of verification?

Comment: Attach some code to make it clear

Comment: The code is divided into several parts. I don't think it will help much. client(response with encoded body)->zuul(it try to transfer the decoded body, but it is throws: "Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens" )->auth server

a similar problem, but in my case it occurred because I pass the body in encrypted, as ssl does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218237/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-character-found-in-method-name-http