# Spring Boot Invalid Token Error after running the application

Tags: spring, exception

Hi I am using Spring Boot application.
And I am getting a weird exception.
First of all, I read some other posts talking about the way to hit the end point is wrong.  But I am NOT even Hitting any end point. I just run the application and leave it.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x020x000x010x000x010xfc0x030x030xc4uy0xed0xf3jP0xae0x96|^0x9b0x1e0xe30x010xeb0x8bsa0xab9F-0x940xf00xecy0x190xf0m0xaf0xc4 ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:269) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

and this happens not right after I run the application.
maybe 5mins after I run the application, it throws this error.
on top of that, when I change my `application.properties` to `application.yml` it throws this error right away.

In fact, the application seems to be working even after throwing this error.
I am guessing this is due to the some environment or configuration issue?

Please let me know if anyone has an idea.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218237/tomcat-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-character-found-in-method-na)

Comment: hmmm, i actually checked this post. but the issue is he is hitting the endpoint, whereas I am not.... but thank you for the help!