# Tomcat 9 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

I can deploy my older version of the application to Tomcat, on Google Cloud, but for the newer version now I have a different front-end template, that's the only difference, and when I wish to deploy it now, I have a connection error page, and I end up at this URL: `manager/html/upload?org.apache.Catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=982F861CA67920658BC340994D5B7A32`
I checked the `catalina.log` file for that day:

```
03-Mar-2022 11:25:07.066 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-36] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing the HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/index.php?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21 ]. The valid characters are defined in R$
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:494)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:269)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
03-Mar-2022 20:54:29.088 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-34] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has fa$
 java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:91)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
03-Mar-2022 20:54:29.088 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-34] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [logback-1] but has failed to stop it. This is ver$
 java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1170)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
03-Mar-2022 20:54:29.089 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-34] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [logback-2] but has failed to stop it. This is ver$
 java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1170)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
03-Mar-2022 20:54:29.089 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-34] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [logback-3] but has failed to stop it. This is ver$
 java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1170)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
03-Mar-2022 20:54:29.090 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-34] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [logback-4] but has failed to stop it. This is ver$
 java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1170)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
 java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1170)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
03-Mar-2022 20:54:29.089 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-34] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [logback-3] but has failed to stop it. This is ver$
 java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1170)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
03-Mar-2022 20:54:29.090 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-34] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [logback-4] but has failed to stop it. This is ver$
 java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1170)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
03-Mar-2022 20:54:29.090 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-34] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [logback-5] but has failed to stop it. This is ver$
 java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1170)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
03-Mar-2022 20:54:29.090 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-34] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [logback-6] but has failed to stop it. This is ver$
 java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1170)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
03-Mar-2022 20:54:30.022 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-36] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop The stop() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] after stop() had already been called$
03-Mar-2022 20:54:30.557 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-36] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context []
03-Mar-2022 20:54:34.062 INFO [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The fo$
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which ca$
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1427)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1052)
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:123)
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:90)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

The only difference is that I'm using different templates for UI. catalina.log mentioned "Invalid character found in the request-target", but I don't understand which character? Could that be a problem?

I'm using Spring Boot

I've discovered this topic: [Tomcat: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218237/tomcat-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-character-found-in-method-na)

I wonder do I have the same problem? But I don't wish to provide an SSL key for my Tomcat.
I have Apache on port 43, it's using https protocol. Then Apache redirects to port 8080 Tomcat.
When I access http mydomain:8080/manager, I wish to deploy my Spring Boot app.
As I already mentioned, my older app can be deployed. But I can't deploy the same app (with the same back-end) but with new templates. Could it be that some code from the front end is making a problem?

UPDATE 2:
It seems my app is working if I upload the war file directly via Google Cloud SSH and then move to webapps. But I can't upload it via Tomcat's Manager page.

I discovered this article, is this related to my issue?
https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/635