# Web Service(backend) deployed by AWS EC2 suddenly running extremely slow

Tags: spring, aws-code-deploy

I'm doing my project by Spring Boot.
There was no problem at all when I tested it in the local Server,
neither did it when I deployed it at first.

But since last afternoon, the web server runs extremely slowly - too slow that I cannot test the functions properly and the server throws time-out-error at the end)

The only error log that I see newly is this:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.2)

2024-02-21T16:49:47.832Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] ssucar.SsucarApplication                 : Starting SsucarApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.7 with PID 4999 (/home/ec2-user/apps/deploy/spring-webapp.jar started by ec2-user in /)
2024-02-21T16:49:47.841Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] ssucar.SsucarApplication                 : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-02-21T16:49:49.917Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-02-21T16:49:50.136Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 194 ms. Found 5 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-02-21T16:49:51.799Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-02-21T16:49:51.839Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-02-21T16:49:51.839Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
2024-02-21T16:49:52.139Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-02-21T16:49:52.141Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4147 ms
2024-02-21T16:49:53.113Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-02-21T16:49:53.265Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final
2024-02-21T16:49:53.360Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-02-21T16:49:54.019Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-02-21T16:49:54.087Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-02-21T16:49:55.178Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@3a7469ca
2024-02-21T16:49:55.181Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-02-21T16:49:55.313Z  WARN 4999 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: MySQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-02-21T16:49:58.405Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-02-21T16:49:58.705Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-02-21T16:50:00.215Z  WARN 4999 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-02-21T16:50:00.276Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2024-02-21T16:50:00.970Z  WARN 4999 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Thymeleaf configuration, or set spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false)
2024-02-21T16:50:01.301Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-02-21T16:50:01.351Z  INFO 4999 --- [           main] ssucar.SsucarApplication                 : Started SsucarApplication in 14.848 seconds (process running for 16.562)
2024-02-21T17:27:18.004Z  INFO 4999 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [MGLNDD_3.38.211.169_80800x0a...]. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:407) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2024-02-21T17:50:42.057Z  INFO 4999 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-02-21T17:50:42.058Z  INFO 4999 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-02-21T17:50:42.067Z  INFO 4999 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms
2024-02-22T05:57:18.969Z  INFO 4999 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-02-22T05:57:18.989Z  INFO 4999 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-02-22T05:57:19.010Z  INFO 4999 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

[image]

I did all the researches about this error, but most suggestions are that it gets a wrong request through https:// instead of http://
I checked all the URL and the developer tools, but I'm getting all the request by http:// so I think there's no problem with that.
Any suggestion?

Comment: See all answers and suggestion in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218237/tomcat-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-character-found-in-method-na. There is a specific AWS one in there as well.

Comment: Thanks, I actually already checked that link and that wasn't a big help - there were no https connection on mine-
however I managed to solve it. Just gonna write here down:

Comment: 1. I installed mysqld in my EC2 instance - which was too much burden to my free tier instance so I made it disabled
2. My codedeploy-agent was disable: so it was turned off whenever I rebooted the instance - I enabled it
3. I used swap memory in case of memory lacking

Comment: Can you confirm your version of Tomcat within the local setup and that of EC2 are the same? Lastly please check access and catalina logs once for the right answer