# can someone help me understand why my api is not working?

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, rest

So i have this register api created

```
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest){

        if (userRepository.findByEmail(registerRequest.getEmail())!=null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Email already exist",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
       User user = new User();
       user.setEmail(registerRequest.getEmail());
       user.setName(registerRequest.getName());
       user.setLastName(registerRequest.getLastName());
       user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registerRequest.getPassword()));
       userRepository.save(user);
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(registerRequest.getEmail(), registerRequest.getPassword())
        );
        return new ResponseEntity<>(jwtUtil.generateToken(
                registerRequest.getEmail(),
                userRepository.findByEmail(registerRequest.getEmail()).getId(),
                registerRequest.getName() +" "+registerRequest.getLastName()
        )
                ,HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }
```

This works fine without any error when i got and run my react project and go to the register page i am not able to register a user.
Also when i hit the same api on postman using
{
"name": "Alice",
"lastName": "Smith",
"email": "alice@example.com",
"password": "password123"
}
i get a error on console like

```
Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x000xf70x010x000x000xf30x030x030x0e0xbca0x910x010xf8.0xc40x840xbecS<0xb5w`"0xf1M0xbe0xa10xcd0xf830xf3y0x8a0x110xc80xf80xca6 ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:271) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2024-03-26 17:11:04.733  INFO 9612 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x000xf70x010x000x000xf30x030x030xc930xfa0xfc0xc70xbd0xf80xfcK0x1b=R0x00t0xf60x1fN0xe1m0x100x84>0x830xf0d0xc8H0xf3e0xb3KC ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:271) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

i have already checked that i am using "post" and there isnt any special characters
I HAVE CHANGED HTTPS TO HTTP AND NOW I AM NOT GETTING THE SAME ERROR RATHER GETTING THE 401 error on postman and still not able to register on the web browser

I update and added try and catch

```
@PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
        try {
            if (userRepository.findByEmail(registerRequest.getEmail()) != null) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Email already exists", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            User user = new User();
            user.setEmail(registerRequest.getEmail());
            user.setName(registerRequest.getName());
            user.setLastName(registerRequest.getLastName());
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registerRequest.getPassword()));
            userRepository.save(user);

            // Attempt authentication after user registration
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(registerRequest.getEmail(), registerRequest.getPassword())
            );

            // Generate JWT token
            String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(
                registerRequest.getEmail(),
                user.getId(),
                registerRequest.getName() + " " + registerRequest.getLastName()
            );

            return new ResponseEntity<>(token, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log the exception or handle it as needed
            e.printStackTrace(); // You can replace this with your logging mechanism
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Failed to register user", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

still no luck

Comment: Are you using https on client? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42319270/6212530

Answer (score 0):

Check configuration whether SSL is enabled or not. If SSL is not enabled then use http in the url instead of https.

Comment: i did although i m not getting the same error but now postman shows me 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE- i ran the project in a different Ide and somehow it works fine now