# Unable to get additional tomcat port on https using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have configured additional port to work on https for an REST endpoint. However, while sending request to this endpoint, application does not negotiate over https instead it uses only http. Framework is on Spring Boot 2.7.5.

```
@Configuration 
public class PublicPortConfig {
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PublicPortConfig.class);

@Value("${server.port.public:19280}")
private int port;

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "server.port.public")
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> publicServletContainerCustomizer (
        ServerProperties serverProperties) {
    logger.info("Configuring public port: {}", port);
    return tomcat -> {          
        Connector connector = new Connector();

        connector.setPort(port);
        connector.setScheme("https");
                    
        SSLHostConfig sslHostConfig = new SSLHostConfig();
        
               sslHostConfig.setCertificateKeystoreFile(serverProperties.getSsl().getKeyStore());
        sslHostConfig.setCertificateKeyPassword(serverProperties.getSsl().getKeyStorePassword());
        sslHostConfig.setCertificateKeystoreType(serverProperties.getSsl().getKeyStoreType());

        connector.addSslHostConfig(sslHostConfig);
        
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
    };
}
}
@RestController
public class ExternalApiController {
    @GetMapping("/api/public")
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello Customer (public)");
    }
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Configuring HttpSecurity via SecurityFilterChain...");
    // @formatter:off
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(AUTH_PATH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "ACTUATOR")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
    http.sessionManagement()
             .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
             .maximumSessions(MAX_SESSION_ACTIVE);
    http.httpBasic()
        .realmName("API Auth via DB or LDAP")
        .and()
        .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(cookieCsrfTokenRepository());
    /**
     * Force Disable for API
     */
    http.csrf().disable();
    // http.cors().disable();
    // @formatter:on

    return http.build();
}
```

ExternalApiController sends response when request is sent on http and not on https. All fully authenticated endpoints works perfectly well on https.

cURL gives following results

```
$ curl --insecure -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET "https://localhost:19280/app/api/public"
```

Response: curl: (35) LibreSSL/3.3.6: error:1404B42E:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Java Backend Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name
[0x160x030x010x01(0x010x000x01$0x030x030\90xe9}0xef0x980x970x1b+0x820x0f0xc10xbc0xde0x8370xfceI0xdey0x100x1f0x99vJ0xa50x7f_0xd9Y ].
HTTP method names must be tokens

Where as http request using cURL

```
$ curl --insecure -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET "http://localhost:19280/app/api/public"
```

Response: Hello Customer (public)

Application is started on 2 ports as per below log
INFO 2023-06-06/17:08:18/GMT+05:30 [app-rest-api] (TomcatWebServer.java:220) (start) Tomcat started on port(s): 9280 (https) 19280 (https) with context path '/app'

Port 9280 is ok. However, anything I access on 19280 throws error.

Comment: Any reason for tweaking WebServerFactoryCustomizer Bean ? Also what do you mean by additional port ?

Comment: Actually my objective was to enable private and public api where public api will only be accessed over internet which will be enabled in firewall.

Comment: it is something to do with SSL as I can see (1) port Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-9280"] (2) port Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-19280"] though it shows Tomcat started on port(s): 9280 (https) 19280 (https). Http nio is for http and not https. Any lead will be off great help

Comment: Let me give it a try & see

Comment: I got the thing working, i will cleanup and post complete solution tomorrow.

Comment: Excellent !! will wait for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Couple of months back I enabled https for our REST API in Spring boot,used self signed certificate for local testing generated using Java keytool

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias team_api -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore gaskit.p12 -storepass pwd -validity 3650
```

And then adding following properties in application.properties

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=${ssl_key_store_type}
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=${ssl_key_store}
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=${ssl_key_store_Password}
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=${ssl_key_alias}
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, I am using Self Signed SSL certificate on the local port which is working. However, having additional https port is not working using the either same or different certificate

Comment: INFO  2023-06-06/17:08:18/GMT+05:30 [app-rest-api] (TomcatWebServer.java:220) (start) Tomcat started on port(s): 9280 (https) 19280 (https) with context path '/app'
 As you can see rest api is available on 2 ports. However, anything I access on 19280 throws error.

Comment: Ahh I see there are 2 Bean of Tomcat in your application context, Listening to respective ports !! But basically in real world we redirect traffic on http to https using load balancer, your application should only support https protocol.

Comment: Maybe possible SSL certificate is not correctly configured on your other port, can you try once by only enabling https and using same certificate, just to check if certificate is not causing this issue. Bcoz the error you posted occurs then only
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41728777/16769477

Comment: SSL Cert is working fine and I able access all endpoints /api/private on https (primary 9280). Only additional port 19280 which is intended for public api end point is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I am able to get Public / Private Api EndPoints by deep dive into Http11NioProtocol. Thanks to Spring Community Documents [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M6/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html) under Section: Enable Multiple Connectors with Tomcat for all explanations.

Please find complete solution below

1. Create Configuration File for Public Api

   ```
   @Configuration
   @PropertySource("classpath:public-api.properties")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "public.ssl")
   @Data
   public class PublicApiConfig {
   private int port;
   private String keyStoreType;
   private String keyStore;
   private String keyStorePassword;
   private String keyAlias;
   private List pathsToMatch;
   }
   ```
2. Configuration File public-api.properties

   ```
   public.ssl.port=19280
   public.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
   public.ssl.key-store=ssl/your_certificate.p12
   public.ssl.key-store-password=your_password
   public.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
   public.ssl.paths-to-match=/api/public
   ```
3. Define `server.public.ssl.port.enabled` in your application.properties and value could be true (Public Access) or false.

```
# true for Public Api Access
server.public.ssl.port.enabled=true
```

4. Create PublicPortCustomizer class

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "server.public.ssl.port.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class PublicPortCustomizer {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PublicPortCustomizer.class);

    @Autowired
    PublicApiConfig publicPortConfig;

    /**
     * Verify if KeyStore is Valid
     */
    private boolean isValidKeyStoreFile(String keyStoreFile, String keyStorePassword, String keyStoreType) {
        try {
            File file = new File(keyStoreFile);
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            keystore.load(fis, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            return true;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        if (isValidKeyStoreFile(publicPortConfig.getKeyStore(), publicPortConfig.getKeyStorePassword(),
                publicPortConfig.getKeyStoreType())) {
            logger.info("Configuring Ssl Public for KeyStore: {}", publicPortConfig.getKeyStore());
            /**
             * Create Connector
             */
            Connector connector = createSslConnector();
            tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
        } else {
            logger.fatal("KeyStore for Public: {} is INVALID", publicPortConfig.getKeyStore());
        }
        return tomcat;
    }

    /**
     * Create Ssl Connector
     * @return
     */
    private Connector createSslConnector() {
        logger.info("Configuring Additional Ssl Connector...");

        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");

        connector.setScheme("https");
        connector.setSecure(true);
        connector.setPort(publicPortConfig.getPort());

        Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();

        protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
        protocol.setKeystoreFile(publicPortConfig.getKeyStore());
        protocol.setKeystorePass(publicPortConfig.getKeyStorePassword());
        protocol.setKeyAlias(publicPortConfig.getKeyAlias());

        return connector;
    }
}
```

5. Define SpringSecurity where Public Api will be accessed through JWT which is controlled in Controller

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        http.sessionManagement()
                 .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        http.httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.requiresChannel(channel -> channel.anyRequest().requiresSecure());
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public FilterRegistrationBean publicEndpointsFilter() {
        return new FilterRegistrationBean(new PublicEndpointsFilter(publicPortConfig.getPort(),
                publicPortConfig.getPathsToMatch()));
    }
}
```

5a) Filters to handle public endpoints.

```
public class PublicEndpointsFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PublicEndpointsFilter.class);

    int publicPort;
    List pathsToMatch;

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     * 
     * @param publicPort
     * @param pathsToMatch
     */
    public PublicEndpointsFilter(int publicPort, List pathsToMatch) {
        this.publicPort = publicPort;
        this.pathsToMatch = pathsToMatch;
        logger.info("Configuring Filter for publicPort: {} pathsToMatch: {}", publicPort, pathsToMatch);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        boolean trustedEndPoint = isRequestForTrustedEndpoint(servletRequest);
        int status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK;
        ///////////////////////
        if (servletRequest.getLocalPort() == publicPort && !trustedEndPoint) {
            status = HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN;
        }
        if (status != HttpServletResponse.SC_OK) {
            logger.warn("Denying request on path: {} publicPort: {} localPort: {} status: {}", request.getRequestURI(),
                    publicPort, servletRequest.getLocalPort(), status);
            response.setStatus(status);
            servletResponse.getOutputStream().close();
            return;
        }
        ///////////////////////
        if (servletRequest.getLocalPort() != publicPort && trustedEndPoint) {
            status = HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN;
        }
        if (status != HttpServletResponse.SC_OK) {
            logger.warn("Denying request on path: {} publicPort: {} localPort: {} status: {}", request.getRequestURI(),
                    publicPort, servletRequest.getLocalPort(), status);
            response.setStatus(status);
            servletResponse.getOutputStream().close();
            return;
        }
        logger.debug("Filter Delegate on path: {} localPort: {} status: {}", request.getRequestURI(),
                request.getLocalPort(), status);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, response);
    }

    /**
     * Verify Path as required for Public Access
     * 
     * @param servletRequest
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isRequestForTrustedEndpoint(ServletRequest servletRequest) {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        boolean ok = false;
        
        for (String pathToMatch : pathsToMatch) {
            String requestPath = request.getContextPath() + pathToMatch;
            ok = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(requestPath);
            logger.debug("Verified path: {} localPort: {}", requestPath, servletRequest.getLocalPort());
        }
        return ok;
    }
```

6. Sample Public / Private Rest Controller

```
@RestController
public class PublicApiHelloController {
    @GetMapping("/api/public")
    public ResponseEntity hello() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello Customer (public)");
    }
}
@RestController
public class PrivateApiHelloController {
    // Requires Authentication
    @GetMapping("/api/private")
    public ResponseEntity hello() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello Staff (private)");
    }
}
```

7. Start Application and you should see

```
INFO  2023-06-08/08:19:27/GMT+05:30 [app-api] (DirectJDKLog.java:173) (log) Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-9280"]
INFO  2023-06-08/08:19:27/GMT+05:30 [app-api] (DirectJDKLog.java:173) (log) Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-19280"]
INFO  2023-06-08/08:19:27/GMT+05:30 [app-api] (TomcatWebServer.java:220) (start) Tomcat started on port(s): 9280 (https) 19280 (https) with context path '/app'
```

Make sure ProtocolHandler starts with https-jsse-nio for all https enabled.

8. Public Api Request

```
curl --insecure -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X GET https://localhost:19280/app/api/public
```

Response:: Hello Customer (public)

9)Private Api Request

```
curl --insecure -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X GET https://localhost:9280/app/api/private
```

Response:: {"timestamp":1686133851868,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized","path":"/app/api/private"}

Unauthorized as private expects Authentication

10. Public Ports are configured in firewall to allow traffic

Thanks