# Error parsing HTTP request header in tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, http, tomcat, coyote

I see this message in tomcat logs but I don't know how to fix it :

```
2024-03-05 11:22:02.633 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] INFO  [] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11Processor@log(175) - Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x01,0x010x000x01(0x030x030x940xb7e0xc70xd4X=0xe10xfa0x900xb5A0xf7I0xb60xeb0xaf|0x130xe50xa70x04zo0x0dIy0xb80xc9=0x15p0x000x000xaa0xc000xc0,0xc0(0xc0$0xc00x140xc00x0a0x000xa50x000xa30x000xa10x000x9f0x00k0x00j0x00i0x00h0x0090x0080x0070x0060x000x880x000x870x000x860x000x850xc020xc0.0xc0*0xc0&0xc00x0f0xc00x050x000x9d0x00=0x0050x000x840xc0/0xc0+0xc0'0xc0#0xc00x130xc00x090x000xa40x000xa20x000xa00x000x9e0x00g0x00@0x00?0x00>0x0030x0020x0010x0000x00E0x00D0x00C0x00B0xc010xc0-0xc0)0xc0%0xc00x0e0xc00x040x000x9c0x00<0x00/0x000x070xc00x110xc00x070xc00x0c0xc00x020x000x050x000x040xc00x120xc00x080x000x160x000x130x000x100x000x0d0xc00x0d0xc00x030x000x0a0x000x150x000x120x000x0f0x000x0c0x000x090x000xff0x010x000x00U0x000x0b0x000x040x030x000x010x020x000x0a0x000x1c0x000x1a0x000x170x000x190x000x1c0x000x1b0x000x180x000x1a0x000x160x000x0e0x000x0d0x000x0b0x000x0c0x000x090x000x0a0x00#0x000x000x000x0d0x00 ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273847/springboot-error-parsing-http-request-header

Comment: please your RestController method code block and the Rest API call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When Spring Boot starts up, it throws the "method names must be tokens" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891866/when-spring-boot-starts-up-it-throws-the-method-names-must-be-tokens-exceptio). But on top: Just an error message does typically not provide enough information. Please check [ask] and provide an [mcve]